# Loop print through two lists to get two columns in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to print my data in two columns. The data which I have

```
print(summary_data) 
[('105689_S2', 9477442, 488850, 563029), ('WT101589_S1', 9849916, 507676, 584819)]
```

I am able to print my data through a loop:

```
for data in summary_data:
    print 'Name                      ', data[0]
    print 'Calculations1', data[0], ':    ', data[1]
    print 'Calculations2', data[0], ':    ', data[2]
    print 'Calculations3', data[0], ':    ', data[3]
    print '-------------------------------------------'
```

Which provides:

```
Sample name         105689_S2
Calculations1 :     9477442
Calculations2 :     488850
Calculations3 :     563029
-------------------------------------------
Sample name         WT101589_S1
Calculations1 :     9849916
Calculations2 :     507676
Calculations3 :     584819
-------------------------------------------
```

I would like my output to be formatted like:

```
Sample name         105689_S2   WT101589_S1
Calculations1 :     9477442   9849916
Calculations2 :     488850   507676
Calculations3 :     563029   584819
-------------------------------------------
```

I have tried

```
zipped = ([list(x) for x in zip(*summary_data)])
for data in zipped:
    print data[0]
```

Which gives:

```
105689_S2
909172
31908
31360
```

But now I am lost on how I can get the two column's printed..Could someone help me?

Comment: Problem is with that i need more than 1 value in the `zip` statement, and all the data is stored in one variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) like this:

```
summary_data = [('105689_S2', 9477442, 488850, 563029), ('WT101589_S1', 9849916, 507676, 584819)]
titles = ['Sample name:', 'Calculations1:', 'Calculations2:', 'Calculations3:']

for item in zip(titles, *summary_data):
    print '{}\t{}\t{}'.format(*item)
```

**Output:**

```
Sample name:     105689_S2       WT101589_S1
Calculations1:   9477442 9849916
Calculations2:   488850  507676
Calculations3:   563029  584819
```

Comment: Hi I have a question. When I try to load in the data `summary_data` which is already defined, I get the error: `print '{}\t{}\t{}'.format(*item)
IndexError: tuple index out of range`. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Make sur that all tuples inside your `summary_data` have the same length as the above ones (which is 3)

Comment: Yes they are all the same! `[('105689_S2', 9477442, 488850, 563029), ('WT101589_S1', 9849916, 507676, 584819)]`

Comment: It doesn't work because I am getting an error when I don't use the line defining `summary_data`. I am undoing the acceptance because of the benefit of others.